# Context error with expansion panels

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Up front: I'm having some trouble with using the mat-expansion-panel component in a way that replicates the official examples.

I started out with the basic code block as outlined in [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview). What this comes out to is pretty direct copy-and-paste; so the files look like

**video.component.html**

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  This is the expansion title
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
<p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
<mat-action-row>
  <button mat-button>Click me</button>
</mat-action-row>
```

**video.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { MatCardModule,MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material';
import { VideoComponent } from './video.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    VideoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatExpansionModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [VideoComponent]
})
export class VideoModule { }
```

**video.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'video-root',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.css']  /* this is a blank file */
})
export class VideoComponent {
  title = 'video';
  /* snipped */
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
}
```

**../styles.css**

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

On page load, I'm getting a console error that points to MatExpansionPanel.html:1:61[image: Firefox console log showing error and error context on MatExpansionPanel.html:1:61]
And then also the expansion panel doesn't ~work~ insofar as it doesn't look or behave like what the documentation shows.
[image: Output of the page]
The button you see doesn't do anything, by the way.

I'm confused because I was just able to use the MatCard module in a way that largely imitated the documentation - the copy-pasted code, along with the import in video.component.ts, made things that behaved right (i.e. behaved like I expected when I used ngFor). This smells like a problem with how I'm bringing the CSS in, but would that cause a console error and cause other angular elements on the page to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been a missing import. Once I added

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

to **video.module.ts** (and added BrowserAnimationsModule to the @NgModule.imports), everything worked properly. I feel like an idiot or the student of an idiot, but posting this here in case anybody else hits the same problem.